# Can any smooth planar curve which is closed, be a base for a 3 dimensional cone?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, analytic-geometry

A cone in 3 dimensions has a vertex and a base. The contour of the base is a circle which is a smooth closed planar curve. Can there be a more general cone which can have any smooth closed planar curve as the contour of its base ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly; if you have some plane curve represented parametrically as $(f(u)\quad g(u))^T$, the surface represented parametrically by

$$\begin{align*}x&=f(u)(1-v)\\y&=g(u)(1-v)\\z&=v\end{align*}$$

is one simple parametrization for a generalized (right) cone whose cross sections are scaled versions of the given plane curve.

Comment: M.: Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Of course, if what you need is a *skew* cone (axis not perpendicular to a coordinate plane), a different approach is needed...